# Relating two fields of one table to one field of another

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have two tables that look as such:

```
Table1               Table2
ID | Appname         ID  | App  | Dependency
------------         -----------------------
1  | App1            1   | 2    |  3
2  | App2            2   | 3    |  1
3  | App3            3   | 2    |  1
etc....               etc...
```

Basically an application can have one or more dependencies that must be complete prior to executing. In Table2, both `App` and `Dependency` relates to the ID field of Table1, but I'm having a difficult time linking these together with SQL without getting errors.

What is the correct way to join the tables so that I get results that look like this:

```
Dependencies:
App2: App3, App1
App3: App1
```

(doesn't have to be laid out like that, but if it can be, that would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use view designer, add Table2, then add Table1 two times.

Select Table1.ID and drag till Table2.App and do the same with Table1_1 and Table2.Dependency.

```
SELECT Table2.Id, 
       Table2.App, 
       Table2.Dependency, 
       Table1.Appname, 
       Table1_1.Appname
FROM 
       Table1 AS Table1_1 
INNER JOIN 
       (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.AppId) 
       ON Table1_1.Id = Table2.Dependency;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It didn't occur to me that I could have multiple instances of Table1 in the design view. Was trying to connect both references to Table1 to the same instance.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.